# Show Loading Image while performing jquery ajax call on a asp.net webform page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

On a ASP.NET Webform page, I have a field for which on focusout, we need to make a jquery ajax call. During this call i want to display a loading gif image. i have already tried the following:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                $("div#divLoading").addClass('show');
                }
       });
$.ajax({
    //call goes in here 
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
        alert("An error occured while fetching the data. Please contact the site administrator.");
        },
    complete: function () {
        $("div#divLoading").removeClass('show');
    }
});
```

following is the CSS i'm using

```
#divLoading.show
        {
            display : block;
            position : fixed;
            z-index: 100;
            background-image : url(../images/ajax-loader.gif);
            background-color:#666;
            opacity : 0.4;
            background-repeat : no-repeat;
            background-position : center;
            left : 0;
            bottom : 0;
            right : 0;
            top : 0;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `show` before `$.ajax()`?

Comment: Yeah I have already tried that.. it doesn't work

Comment: I think more code and html are needed to figure out what's wrong.